# How to remove special 'M-BM-' character with sed

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I have file that was created by copying content from DOCX document with LibreOffice into text file. I have modified file with `sed` to remove additional spaces and other stuff but then I noticed space that was immune to regular command:

```
sed -r 's:some-text :some-text:g' -i file
```

After using `cat -A file` I found out that this looks like this:

```
<p>M-BM- Lorem ipsum</p>
```

How to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying a lot of things, I have finally found solution. To replace that weird character with sed, you need to copy and paste exact text that contains that weird space near it, and then paste it directly into sed command:

`sed -r 's:paste-here:<p>:g' -i file`

Which will look like this in sed command:

`sed -r 's:<p> :<p>:g' -i file`

but it will work anyway.

Answer (score 19):

The `M-BM-` characters are an ASCII representation of byte sequence `0xc2 0xa0`, which is the UTF8 encoding of unicode character `A0` - a non-breaking space character. This character can be inserted in both LibreOffice and Microsoft Word documents using the key sequence <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>.

For example if we create a new .odt document in LibreOffice and type ABC<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>DEF, then `Save As... Text` (ignoring the warning that the document may contain features that cannot be saved in that format), then view the resulting .txt file with `cat`:

```
$ cat nbsp.txt 
ABC DEF
```

and then again with the `-v` switch to show non-printing characters

```
$ cat -v nbsp.txt 
M-oM-;M-?ABCM-BM- DEF
```

Note that we also get an initial sequence `M-oM-;M-?` or hexadecimal `0xef 0xbb 0xbf` which is the UTF8 [byte order mark (BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) consistent with the file type reported by the `file` command i.e.

```
$ file nbsp.txt 
nbsp.txt: UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text
```

Using `od` to print the hexadecimal values in byte order we see

```
$ od -tx1 nbsp.txt
0000000 ef bb bf 41 42 43 c2 a0 44 45 46 0a
0000014
```

It is possible to manipulate these characters using standard tools like `sed` or `tr` by specifying the hex codes as escape sequences e.g. to replace the non-breaking space with a plain ASCII space

```
$ sed 's/\xc2\xa0/ /g' nbsp.txt
ABC DEF
```

Checking again with `od` confirms the replacement by an ordinary ASCII space 0x20 (decimal 32)

```
$ sed 's/\xc2\xa0/ /g' nbsp.txt | od -tx1
0000000 ef bb bf 41 42 43 20 44 45 46 0a
0000013
```

In gnome-terminal (and maybe other UTF8-aware terminal emulators), it's also possible to enter the unicode *code point value* directly using the key sequence <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> followed by a hexidecimal value then the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key - the sequence shows up initially as u̲.̲.̲.̲ but then the character should compose when you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> e.g. for the same non-breaking space replacement we can do

```
$ sed 's/Ctrl+Shift+ua0
```

which displays as

```
$ sed 's/̲/̲u̲a̲0̲
```

and then completes as

```
$ sed 's/ / /g' nbsp.txt
ABC DEF
```

Using `cat -v` we can confirm the `M-BM-` sequence has become an ordinary space

```
$ sed 's/ / /g' nbsp.txt | cat -v
M-oM-;M-?ABC DEF
```

You may want to look at more generic encoding converters such as *iconv* and *uconv* as well.

Comment: After almost 2 years, your solution helped me to get rid of another pesky characters that couldn't just be copied and pasted as in my solution. So it is certainly more universal one, especially when new lines are concerned.

Answer (score 2):

"cat -v file " will show the non-printing characters in the file. Just redirect the output to some temporary file and use vim for replacing the M-BM- characters with nothing.

%s/M-BM- //g

Easiest solution.

Comment: Or just use sed: `cat -v file` | sed -i 's/M-BM-/g'`

Answer (score 1):

You can remove ^M from the files directly via sed command, e.g.:

```
sed -i'.bak' s/\r//g *.*
```

If you're happy with the changes, remove the .bak files:

```
rm -v *.bak
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also paste the special unicode char in your sed command, like this:

```
sed 's/ / /g'
```

Answer (score 0):

little script for remove this devil M-BM- caracter ! ;) Just in case will be help any people.

```
#!/bin/bash
#############################################################################
# SCRIPT:   M-BM-Remover.sh
# DESCRIPTION:
#           This script will be able to detect hidden caracter "M-BM-",
#               And/Or remove this !
# REVISIONS:
#           2014/06/11  YG
#____________________________________________________________________________
#
# PARAMETERS:
#  > $1  :TARGET,      (e.g. '"*.sh"' )
#  > $2  :ACTION,      (e.g. 'remove' )
#  > $2  :BACKUP,      (e.g. '' )
#
#############################################################################

TARGET=$1
ACTION=$2
BACKUP=$3

if [ "$TARGET" = "" ]
then
    echo 'Need to choose target file'
    echo 'M-BM-Remover [TARGET] [show/remove] [backup]'
    echo 'Example : M-BM-Remover "*.sh" remove backup'
    exit
fi

echo "ACTION = $ACTION";
echo "TARGET = $TARGET";
echo

if [ "$ACTION" = "show" ]
then
    for file in $TARGET
    do
        if [ "$file" != "M-BM-Remover.sh" ]
        then
            echo "Traitement de $file ..."
            cat -v $file | grep M-BM-
            NB=`cat -v $file | grep M-BM- | wc -l`
            echo "Occurence(s) : $NB"
        fi
    done 
fi

if [ "$ACTION" = "remove" ] || [ "$ACTION" = "" ]
then
    for file in $TARGET
    do
        if [ "$file" != "M-BM-Remover.sh" ]
        then
            echo "Traitement de $file ..."
            NB=`cat -v $file | grep M-BM- | wc -l`
            if [ "$BACKUP" = "backup" ]
            then
                cat $file > $file.bak
            fi
            cat -v $file.bak | sed s/M-BM-//g > $file
            echo "Occurence(s) removed : $NB"
        fi
        echo
    done 
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

A easy solution was offered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/36371440/906489 by [Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/648658/jens)

```
tr -d '\200-\377' m.txt > m-no-8bit.txt
```

That removes all values from 128 to 255, which is octal 200 to 377 (which are the "troublesome non-printable characters"